# The /top-answer-tags method is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v1.1

I tried the new `/top-answer-tags` method on Ask Ubuntu, but it isn't working:

**URL:**

http://api.askubuntu.com/1.1/users/5/top-answer-tags

**Output:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "A generic error has occurred on the server; developers have been notified."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... subtle.

Looks like, technically, some of the top score you've earned there are on tags that no longer actually exist.  I'm filtering those out for the time being (so you look like a user who hasn't yet got 30 top tags)...  probably going to change that to just drop down however many tags on the list.  Depends on how expensive that turns out to be though.